# Radio button style in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to make each list item hide the circle on/off drawable **without defining a custom alert dialog**?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSwVt.jpg]

That is...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom AlertDialog, which is without all the radio buttons and is only a single ListView with onTouch event for each ListViewItem. Some example of creating a custom dialog box you could find here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html There is an example for adding ListView in the `Adding a list` chapter. I hope it helps you :)